# What is supposed to happen on "The Day when All are One"?

Tags: transformers

In the iconic 80's feature animated film, *Transformers: The Movie*, the Autobots mention:

> the Day when All are One.

- What does *all becoming one* mean, in Transformers mythology?
- When was it first mentioned?
- Is it just an Autobot belief, or do the other Transformers factions also believe in it?

Answer (score 3):

### The Transformers United Without Enmity or War

In the aftermath of the battle with Unicron, Rodimus Prime's optimistic speech is met with the response "'til all are one!" (the image below is from the comic adaptation of the movie).

[image: Rodimus Prime]

Reformed and transfigured by the Creation Matrix, Rodimus clearly understands his (almost Messianic) role in terms of an end to hostilities with the Decepticons (with whom the Autobots have been briefly united by the existential threat of Unicron) and the ushering in of a peaceful age where the badges of Autobot and Decepticon are no longer needed.

For more about this phrase, see this page on [TFwiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/'Til_all_are_one).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase has never been fully explained in canon. However, there are a few possibilities:

1. Until all Cybertronians are united under one peaceful banner. In the third season episode "The Burden Hardest to Bare", Galvatron seizes the Matrix of Leadership and says "Now, **all shall become one**, under Galvatron's rule."
2. Until all Cybertronians are united *in* the Matrix. Rhinox described the Matrix as the place "where **all are one**".
3. In the IDW continuity (which is separate from the traditional G1 continuity), there exists a prophecy that all Cybertronians will become one. The meaning of the prophecy is vague and some characters have interpreted it as a call to *combine* all Cybertronians into one being, kick starting the race to gestalt technology.

Comment: Isn't that a Stairway to Heaven reference?

Comment: @DeerHunter interesting. Care to explain the relation with the song?

Comment: @DeerHunter "all are one, and one is all" is not original to Zeppelin - it's a common maxim in many spiritual traditions. For instance, it can be found in many 19th century Christian works: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22all+are+one%22+%22one+is+all%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899